# Parsing JSON variable data from Pyomo output

Tags: json, vba

I have written a Python/Pyomo model that spits out a json file, an extract of which is below:

```
> { "Problem": [
>     {
>         "Lower bound": 2923356.2144,
>         "Name": "unknown",
>         "Number of constraints": 4487,
>         "Number of nonzeros": 8579,
>         "Number of objectives": 1,
>         "Number of variables": 3455,
>         "Sense": "minimize",
>         "Upper bound": 2923356.2144
>     } ], "Solution": [
>     {
>         "number of solutions": 1,
>         "number of solutions displayed": 1
>     },
>     {
>         "Constraint": "No values",
>         "Gap": 0.0,
>         "Message": null,
>         "Objective": {
>             "obj": {
>                 "Value": 2923356.2144
>             }
>         },
>         "Problem": {},
>         "Status": "feasible",
>         "Variable": {
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal1,16]": {
>                 "Value": 0.0899674999999999
>             },
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal1,17]": {
>                 "Value": 0.537404375
>             },
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal1,18]": {
>                 "Value": 0.537404375
>             },
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal1,19]": {
>                 "Value": 0.582716875
>             },
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal1,20]": {
>                 "Value": 0.2049675
>             },
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal2,10]": {
>                 "Value": 0.87062375
>             },
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal2,11]": {
>                 "Value": 0.82999875
>             },
>             "CapacityFactor[Coal2,12]": {
>                 "Value": 0.81687375
>             },
```

I want to extract all of the "Variable" data from the json file, so that I can manipulate this in Excel, Tableau, etc. I've written some VBA code, using the JsonConverter (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON), to try to do this:

```
Sub jsonConversion()

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim JsonText As String
Dim Parsed As Dictionary
Dim NumberOfVariables As Integer

Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("c:\users\s_d_n\OneDrive - Kuungana\Modelling\KEMS\OptimisationResults_20210110.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close

Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)

NumberOfVariables = Parsed("Solution")(2)("Variable").Count

Dim Variable As Variant
ReDim Variable(1 To NumberOfVariables) As Variant

Dim i As Integer
Dim VariableDescription As String

For i = 1 To NumberOfVariables
    VariableDescription = "CapacityFactor[Coal1,16]"
    Variable(i) = Parsed("Solution")(2)("Variable")(VariableDescription)
Next
```

This code seems to work until the final section. I have two questions:

- The final line of code "Variable(i)...etc" seems to read an 'empty' value. I'm not sure why.
- Once I have sussed that out, I will want to read the key name for each variable, i.e. to find "VariableDescription". I'm not sure how to do that either?!

Apologies if I'm missing something simple - I'm not using these languages day-to-day and do not profess to be an expert!! Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating a dictionary's key and values looks something like this:

```vb
Dim s, k, d

Set s = Parsed("Solution")(2)("Variable")

For Each k in s
    Set d = s(k) 'inner dictionary object as value
    Debug.Print k, d("Value")  'CapacityFactor[Coal1,16]    0.0899674999999999  etc...
Next k
```

Comment: Many thanks, Tim. I have implemented this and set up some watches in VBA to check what is happening. I can see that the 'k' part is working, i.e the code is picking up the keys. But the 's(k)' part is not working; this is triggering a "Run-time error 450: Wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment". It feels like I'm very close - apologies if I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: Sorry I missed the nested Dictionary object which wraps the `Variable` values.  Edited my answer.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks so much, Tim.